# How to move a table(or other content) next to vertical navigation bar

Tags: html, css, html-table, navbar, css-tables

I've tried searching for a solution, but none of them have helped. Right now I have a vertical navigation bar, on the left, and I have also made a table, but the table is resting underneath the navigation bar. I cannot figure out how to make them go side by side. I think it may have to do with me not having a div of any sort, but when I tried to add a div it didn't fix the problem, unless I did something wrong with where I placed it or with my CSS. Here's what I got at the moment.

```css
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background: lavenderblush;
    }
    
    header {
      padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
      font-size: 55px;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 1px;
      padding: 0px;
      border: 0px solid honeydew;
      width: 120px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    a {
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      background: honeydew;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: cadetblue;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    li.active a {
      color: black;
      background: lavenderblush;
      border: 1px solid lavenderblush;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 500px;
        font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter|Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <header>
          <h1>Italian Glossary</h1>
        </header>
    
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="italianfood.html">Food</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Animals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Verbs</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <table align="center">
          <tr><th>Italian</th><th>English</th></tr>
          <tr><td>Acqua</td><td>Water</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Aglio</td><td>Garlic</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Arancia</td><td>Orange</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Banana</td><td>Banana</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bevanda</td><td>Beverage</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bira</td><td>Beer</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Biscotto</td><td>Cookie</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bistecca</td><td>Steak</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Burro</td><td>Butter</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Caffe</td><td>Coffee</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Caramella</td><td>Candy</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Carne</td><td>Meat</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Carota</td><td>Carrot</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cioccolato</td><td>Chocolate</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cipolla</td><td>Onion</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Creama</td><td>Cream</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Dolce</td><td>Sweet</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Fagiolo</td><td>Bean</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Fragola</td><td>Strawberry</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Frito</td><td>Fried</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Frutta</td><td>Fruit</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Funghi</td><td>Mushroom</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Gelato</td><td>Ice Cream</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Ghiaccio</td><td>Ice </td></tr>
          <tr><td>Insalata</td><td>Salad</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Latte</td><td>Millk</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Limonata</td><td>Lemonade</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Limone</td><td>Lemon</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Maiale</td><td>Pork</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Manzo</td><td>Beef</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Marmellata</td><td>Jam</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Mela</td><td>Apple</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Olio</td><td>Oil</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pane</td><td>Bread</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Panino</td><td>Sandwich</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pasta</td><td>Pasta</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Patata</td><td>Potato</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pepe</td><td>Pepper</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pesce</td><td>Fish</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pollo</td><td>Chicken</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pomodoro</td><td>Tomato</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Riso</td><td>Rice</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Sale</td><td>Salt</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Salciccia</td><td>Sausage</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Succo</td><td>Juice</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Tacchino</td><td>Turkey</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Te</td><td>Tea</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Torta</td><td>Cake</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Uovo</td><td>Egg</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Uva</td><td>Grape</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Verdura</td><td>Vegetables</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Vino</td><td>Wine</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Zucchero</td><td>Sugar</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Zuppa</td><td>Soup</td></tr>
        </table>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `display` from `nav` element and wrap the table in a div

```css
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background: lavenderblush;
    }
    
    header {
      padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
      font-size: 55px;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 1px;
      padding: 0px;
      border: 0px solid honeydew;
      width: 120px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    a {
      font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
      display: block;
      width: 80px;
      background: honeydew;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: cadetblue;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    li.active a {
      color: black;
      background: lavenderblush;
      border: 1px solid lavenderblush;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 500px;
        font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    nav { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
    .table-wrapper { display: inline-block; }

**HTML:**
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter|Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <header>
          <h1>Italian Glossary</h1>
        </header>
    
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="italianfood.html">Food</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Animals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Verbs</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="table-wrapper">
         <table align="center">
          <tr><th>Italian</th><th>English</th></tr>
          <tr><td>Acqua</td><td>Water</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Aglio</td><td>Garlic</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Arancia</td><td>Orange</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Banana</td><td>Banana</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bevanda</td><td>Beverage</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bira</td><td>Beer</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Biscotto</td><td>Cookie</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Bistecca</td><td>Steak</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Burro</td><td>Butter</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Caffe</td><td>Coffee</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Caramella</td><td>Candy</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Carne</td><td>Meat</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Carota</td><td>Carrot</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cioccolato</td><td>Chocolate</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Cipolla</td><td>Onion</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Creama</td><td>Cream</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Dolce</td><td>Sweet</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Fagiolo</td><td>Bean</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Fragola</td><td>Strawberry</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Frito</td><td>Fried</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Frutta</td><td>Fruit</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Funghi</td><td>Mushroom</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Gelato</td><td>Ice Cream</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Ghiaccio</td><td>Ice </td></tr>
          <tr><td>Insalata</td><td>Salad</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Latte</td><td>Millk</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Limonata</td><td>Lemonade</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Limone</td><td>Lemon</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Maiale</td><td>Pork</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Manzo</td><td>Beef</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Marmellata</td><td>Jam</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Mela</td><td>Apple</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Olio</td><td>Oil</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pane</td><td>Bread</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Panino</td><td>Sandwich</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pasta</td><td>Pasta</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Patata</td><td>Potato</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pepe</td><td>Pepper</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pesce</td><td>Fish</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pollo</td><td>Chicken</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Pomodoro</td><td>Tomato</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Riso</td><td>Rice</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Sale</td><td>Salt</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Salciccia</td><td>Sausage</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Succo</td><td>Juice</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Tacchino</td><td>Turkey</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Te</td><td>Tea</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Torta</td><td>Cake</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Uovo</td><td>Egg</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Uva</td><td>Grape</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Verdura</td><td>Vegetables</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Vino</td><td>Wine</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Zucchero</td><td>Sugar</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Zuppa</td><td>Soup</td></tr>
         </table>
        </div>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix this you can float the `nav` element to the left. That way the table will show up to the right of it, and only below it when the screen is not wide enough to show them side by side.

```
nav {
    float: left;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5fxnpwLu/